# Getting first day of a given month in PHP?

Tags: php, date

I've been trying to get the code below to work, and while it worked with June it is not working with July.

The below results in a value of 3 for $first_day_of_month when it should be 2 for Tuesday.

```
$date = strtotime('20140702'); // July 02, 2014
$month = date('m',$date);
$year = date('Y',$date);
$days_in_month = date('t',$date);
$first_day_of_month = date('w', strtotime($year . $month . 01)); // sunday = 0, saturday = 6
```

Comment: May want to remove the line "$days_in_month = date('t',$date);" since it's not related to your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`strtotime`](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function supports [relative time formats](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php). You can just do this instead:

```
$date = strtotime('20140702');
$first_date = strtotime('first day of this month', $date);
$first_day_of_month = date('w', $first_date);
```

The second parameter to `strtotime` provides the time that the relative format will be relative to. You can use this to easily calculate dates relative to a particular point, as shown above.

Comment: I have a format like `mm.YYY`,eg:`07.2017` and i need to find first and last date of this month-year.Please Consider this problem -@Alexis King

Answer (score 2):

You would have to cast 01 to a string or else php will compute the time for 2014071 rather 20140701

```
strtotime($year . $month . '01')
```

Answer (score 2):

You should look at [mktime()](https://www.php.net/mktime).

In your case your best approach would be:

```
$date = strtotime('20140702'); // July 02, 2014
$month = date('m',$date);
$year = date('Y',$date);
$days_in_month = date('t',$date);


$first_day_of_month = date('w', mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year)); // sunday = 0, saturday = 6
```

As a bonus you can also get the last day of the month

```
$last_date_of_month = mktime(0,0,0,$month+1,0,$year);
```